# how to show a django application inside a site in wordpress

Tags: python, django, wordpress

I have a site made in wordpress and i´d like to show my django application inside this site. I don´t know how to do that. How do call my django application and show it inside the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other option - far more work and technical than using an iframe - is to show the content in the WordPress site by using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (on the Django app) then pulling in the content via API requests.

It would be a lot of work, but well worth learning and provide you the most flexibility.

The steps would be

1. Install django-rest-framework for your Django app
2. Setup up and configure an API
3. Either use PHP on the server or JavaScript on the frontend to pull in the content from the API

Comment: I got it. I had to modify ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Answer (score 0):

try to detail your issue. Do you need a link in your wordpress´site  ? have you tried loading it using [iframe](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) ?

It´s really important to show inside a wordpress´site ?

Comment: I´ve already tried to use iframe. My aplication is on pythonanywhere. I include a link in wordpress, but it didn´t word. Yes, it´s important to show inside a wordpress site.

Comment: well, can you post error message ? The error was on django side or Wordpress side ? Check that on django side , in your settings.py you ´ve made changes to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], like change this * to a more secure setting, like 'patricia_app_url.pythonanywhere.com'  .  See [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/FollowingTheDjangoTutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Only using iframes, because they bore are diffrerent frameworks using different languages etc... so you will make to make one iframe inside your wordpress page and inside that page to load one url from your django application

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp